# Error: break statement not within loop, when in fact it is?

Tags: c++

G++ compiler gives the following error:

`error: break statement not within loop or switch`

While my code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int number;

int main() {
    cout << "Let's check whether an integer is even or odd." << endl;
    cout << "Input new for checking a new number." << endl;
    cout << "Input 0 when done." << endl;

    cout << "Enter a number to check whether it's even or odd." << endl << endl;
    cin >> number;
    if (number == 0) {
        cout << "Aborted." << endl;
        break;
    } else if (number % 2 == 0) {
        cout << "Number is even." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Number is odd." << endl;
    }

    return (0);
}
```

As you can see, the `break` statement **is** within a loop, an `if` loop, to be precise. So why is it giving this error?

Comment: `if` is not a loop.

Comment: There ain't no such thing as an `if loop`. Wherever you got this idea? Loops are introduced with keywords `for`, `while` and `do`, and no others.

Comment: An if block isn't a loop. What you're trying to do is achieved by using the return statement.

Comment: Well, there was this ebook with this piece of code: `for (n=10; n>0; n--) { cout << n << ", "; if (n==3) { cout << "countdown aborted!"; break; } }` So, the `break` will work here because the `if` statement is enclosed in a loop (`for`)? Doesn't `break` has to limit its usage to the `if` only?

Comment: 1. That `break` will cause the containing for loop to exit. 2. I don't understand your second question.

Comment: break only works in for and while loops, so in that example, the break breaks out of the for loop. It has nothing to do with the if.

Comment: @Abhimanyu `break` exits the *nearest* loop, so in the code in the book it breaks out of the `for` loop because that is the nearest loop structure.  `if` is not a loop structure.

Comment: @Sam And `do/while` loops, and switch statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is enough clear

> error: break statement not within **loop** or **switch**

Where is there a loop or a swictch statement in your code with which you are using the break statement?

Simply remove the break statement from here

```
if (number==0) {
        cout<<"Aborted."<<endl;
        break;
}
```

and write simply

```
if (number==0) {
        cout<<"Aborted."<<endl;
}
```

There is also written in your program to use a loop. So the program could look like

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "Let's check whether an integer is even or odd." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Input new for checking a new number." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Input 0 when done."<< std::endl;

    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "\nEnter a number to check whether it's even or odd (0-exit): "; 

        int number = 0;
        std::cin >> number;

        if ( number == 0 ) break;

        if ( number % 2 == 0 ) 
        {
            std::cout<< "Number is even." << std::endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            std::cout << "Number is odd." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But that way I'll have to restart the programme to perform another judgement...

Comment: What does `while (true)` do? I also thought of enclosing it within a `while` loop, but couldn't figure out the condition/statement...

Comment: @Abhimanyu it means an infinite loop. You can exit the loop only when you will enter 0 to number.

Comment: Oh! Only if I knew it... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"break" is meant to break out of switch/do/while/for loops (not "if" statements).  There is no need for a break in your example, the flow of the program will just continue onto the "return(0)" statement when it reaches where you have the break statement now.

Comment: Well, that way I'll have to restart the programme to perform another judgement (even or odd)...

Comment: Then put your code into a loop!

Answer (score 0):

The break statement works only if it is in a loop. By loop in C++, that means for loop, while loop, and do... while loop. The `if` is to test the condition on when to break away from the loop.

If you want your program to work (without restarting), put your testing if statements into a loop (for example, a for loop).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest loop that I use is:

```
do
{
   if (number==0) 
   {
      cout<<"Aborted."<<endl;
      break;
   }
   else if( ...  )
   ...


}while(0);
```

This will loop exactly once.